# Выполнение команды screen Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

Как возможно выполнить команду в скрине, не заходя в него?
Что-бы вписать команду **cmd1** в **screen1** я должен:

```
screen -x screen1
cmd1
CTRL+A D
```

Мне необходимо:

```
screen -cmd screen1 cmd1 (Как пример)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно `screen -d -m cmd1`

По факту `-d` как раз делает то, что Вы просите - нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> после выполнения команды.

Парный вопрос https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Мне необходимо зайти в скрин, выполнить команду и выйди одним действием. Данный пример работает в уже ОТКРЫТОМ скрине

Comment: открываете терминал, пишите команду. Он сам откроет терминал, запустит команду и сразу отключится от скрина

Answer (score 1):

Как писали выше -d -m +  ещё удобно задать имя сессии -S

```
screen -dmS ScreenName /path/2/cmd1
```

подключиться к сессии:

```
screen -S ScreenName -r
```

завершить не заходя в неё (пристрелить)

```
screen -S ScreenName -X quit
```